# How do I read text files within a zip file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So say I have a zip file named "files.zip"
it contains
"text1.txt":

```
words
```

and 
"text2.txt":

```
other words
```

How do I tell python to open and read the text1.txt file? I know that usually to open a text file outside of a zip file I would just do this:

```
file = open('text1.txt','r')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module like so:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')
file = zip.read('text1.txt')
```

Don't forget to import zipfile module: `import zipfile`

Comment: It's probably better to use the `with ... as` formulation, as at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11482347/2336725

Comment: @Teepeemm why? If you need full text to parse xml as an example

Comment: @Teepeemm is that just like the with open () function in python?

Comment: this will return `bytes`. it does not decode the bytes into a `str` (unicode)

Answer (score 27):

If you need to open a file inside a ZIP archive in text mode, e.g. to pass it to `csv.reader`, you can do so with `io.TextIOWrapper`:

```py
import io
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("files.zip") as zf:
    with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open("text1.txt"), encoding="utf-8") as f:
        ...
```

Comment: For Python 3.x, I believe this answer — particularly the use of io.TextIoWrapper — is necessary to properly read a text file as text and not as a stream of bytes

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.8, it's been possible to construct [Path](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/zipfile.html#path-objects) objects for zipfile contents, and use their [read_text](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.Path.read_text) method to read them as text.  Since Python 3.9 it's been possible to specify text mode in the path object's [open](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.Path.open) method.

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile('spam.zip') as zf:
    # Create a path object.
    path = zipfile.Path(zf, at='somedir/somefile.txt')

    # Read all the contents (Python 3.8+):
    contents = path.read(encoding='UTF-8')

    # Or open as as file (Python 3.9+):
    with path.open(encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        # Do stuff
```