# Large Zip Files with Zipfile Module Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I have never used the zip file module before. I have a directory that contains thousands of zip files i need to process. These files can be up to 6GB big. I have looked through some documentation but a lot of them are not clear on what the best methods are for reading large zip files without needing to extract.

I stumbled up this: [Read a large zipped text file line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482342/read-a-large-zipped-text-file-line-by-line-in-python/11482347#11482347)

So in my solution I tried to emulate it and use it like I would reading a normal text file with the with open function

```
with open(odfslogp_obj, 'rb', buffering=102400) as odfslog
```

So I wrote the following based off the answer from that link:

```
for odfslogp_obj in odfslogs_plist:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(odfslogp_obj, mode='r') as z:
        with z.open(buffering=102400) as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line)
```

But this gives me an "unexpected keyword" error for z.open()

Question is, is there documentation that explains what keywords, the z.open() function would take? I only found one for the .ZipFile() function.

I wanna make sure my code isn't using up too much memory while processing these files line by line.

odfslogp_obj is a Path object btw

When I take off the buffering and just have z.open(), I get an error saying: `TypeError: open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Comment: Zip files can contain multiple files; you can't just open a zipfile itself for reading in a sensible way. Do you need to iterate over each file in each zipfile?

Comment: @AKX The zip files should only have 1 file in them. But if it has multiple, then yes I need to iterate over each file in the zip file. But they are only supposed to have 1 file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've opened the zipfile, you still need to open the individual files it contains. That the second `z.open` you had problems with. Its not the builtin python `open` and it doesn't have a "buffering" parameter. See [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)

Once the zipfile is opened you can enumate its files and open them in turn. ZipFile.open opens in binary mode, which may be a different problem, depending on what you want to do with the file.

```
for odfslogp_obj in odfslogs_plist:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(odfslogp_obj, mode='r') as z:
        for name in z.namelist():
            with z.open(name) as f:
                for line in f:
                    print(line)
```

Comment: Is zip.open() a good way to handle big zip files then? Or is there a way to use the built in with open() to be able to parse out the contents of the file inside the zip file without having to extract?

Comment: I'd correct your answer to say "for name in z.namelist()" and indent third for loop

Comment: I'm not sure what parse without extract means. The file needs to be decompressed to be parsed.

Comment: Oh I meant extracted in the local directory its in. So the zip module does some sort of decompression then? Just through python? I'm trying to save as much performance whenever and wherever I can

Comment: Zipfiles are optionally compressed and there are several protocols that may be used. You can get parallelism by having a `multiprocessing.Pool` do extracts in parallel in subprocesses. Pass the list of zipfiles to the processes and let the unzip.

Comment: But thats if I want to extract no? I don't want to extract if I don't need to. Seems LIke the moduleis able to read the files in byte form so no longer an issue then. I was just wondering a bit about the inner mechanisms of it

Comment: Zipfiles have a header and a potentially compressed blob for each file. A directory of files is appended to the end. The file is opened when you create the `ZipFile` object and each time you `z.open` and internal file, a pseudo-file object is created that remembers both the position in the real file and the virtual position in the file being zipped / unzipped. You could potentailly process this stuff yourself, but that's what the `zipfile` module does, so you won't save a lot.